# Groovy classpath not set up properly by <groovy> Ant task

Tags: ant, groovy, classpath

My Groovy script depends on some libraries. This is what I have at the top of my script.

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group = 'net.sf.json-lib', module = 'json-lib', version = '2.3',
        classifier = 'jdk15'),
    @Grab(group = 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder',
        module = 'http-builder', version = '0.7.1'),
    @Grab(group = 'commons-cli', module = 'commons-cli', version = '1.2')])
```

When I run the script from command line using `groovy` executable, everything works properly. The artefacts get  downloaded and the script runs.

However, if I try to execute the same script from Apache Ant using `<groovy src="myscript.groovy" fork="true" />` (simplified), the artefacts also get resolved and downloaded but then I get `[groovy] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException`.

The Apache Ant installation uses `groovy-all-2.3.6.jar` that I have copied from the Groovy installation that I have installed, so they should be pretty much identical.

What am I missing? How can I make the `<groovy>` task work and use the downloaded jars?

**UPDATE I**

> The issue I believe is that Grape and Ant use different classloaders so the artifacts aren't visible to Ant. Can you try adding this: @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true) to your groovy script after the @Grape annotations?

If I do that I get `General error during conversion: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab`.

**UPDATE II**

I have also tried this now:

```
import groovy.grape.Grape;
Grape.grab(group:"commons-cli", module:"commons-cli", version:"1.2", classLoader:this.class.classLoader.rootLoader)
//...
```

It does not help. I get compile time error then:

```
   [groovy] Exception in thread "main" Script Failed: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
   [groovy] C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded_script_in_2825216891785993632groovy_Ant_task: 18: unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
   [groovy]  @ line 18, column 1.
   [groovy]    import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
   [groovy]    ^
```

Comment: The issue I believe is that Grape and Ant use different classloaders so the artifacts aren't visible to Ant. Can you try adding this: @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true) to your groovy script after the @Grape annotations?

Comment: @DakotaBrown: I have tried that. See my update to the question.

Comment: Why would you need to explicitly import HTTPBuilder when Grape is supposed to handle that for you by grabbing org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the @Grab and use the static .grab() method Grape offers. It allows you to specify a the rootLoader classloader which Ant can see:

```
import groovy.grape.Grape;

Grape.grab(group:"commons-cli", module:"commons-cli", version:"1.2", classLoader:this.class.classLoader.rootLoader)
<repeat for rest of @Grab>
```

Comment: That does not seem to help. See my UPDATE II.